# No way to get per-transaction commission fee in new Yodlee API? (/ysl/restserver/v1)

Tags: yodlee

I was trying to extract commission cost at a per-transaction basis, this field does exist in old [Aggregation style](https://developer.yodlee.com/Aggregation_API/Aggregation_Services_Guide/Data_Model/Investment_Transaction) api but not in [new API](https://developer.yodlee.com/Yodlee_API/Data_Model#DataModel_Transactions) data model.

Any suggestions / alternative solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please explain in detail-

> -End-point url which you are using in the old API.
>
> -The field details in the response , which returns the required commission cost.

So this will help us to give you suggestions accordingly.

Regards,

Krithik